# Multiple Files Extension in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a question regarding multiple File extensions. There are two files which I need to check whether it exists or not

**File Names**

```
Data.success
Data.failure
```

It works fine when I load one file b

```
success.file=Data.success
```

However, when I try to load multiple file extensions it doesn't file

```
success.file=Data.success|Data.failure
```

**Code**
{{FilePath}}?fileName={{success.file}}&&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true

Answer (score 0):

Use the include option instead which is a regular expression, there you can set a pattern to match your files

And then do not use the fileName option.

See more in the Camel documentation: http://camel.apache.org/file2 about these options and how they work.